# Drawing a label using pyglet.text.layout.TextLayout(document)

Tags: pyglet

I would like to draw a label that contains text that has different styles at the beginning and at the end.
When drawaing it like

```
label = pyglet.text.layout.TextLayout('Hello, {bold True}world{bold False}')
label.draw()
```

It draws the text, but it draws it at the very bottom of the window. How do I set its position?

Comment: https://pyglet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/modules/text/layout.html

Comment: @Rabbid76 I was looking at this for a very long time, trying .position, etc., but for the love of god, cannot figure it out. Now I am using pyglet.text.HTMLLabel, but TextLayout would be fancier.